# splitting code using laravel mix for a project that only uses vue on several pages

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm currently doing front-end optimization for a project and I'm stuck with code splitting..

basically what I'm trying to achieve is splitting code and vendors and load specific ones only when needed.

Currently, I use the default mix setup and all the dependencies are imported into `app.js`. So I need to include `app.js` on every page, which is very inefficient because in my project, most of the pages don’t use vue and I used some REAL big vue plugins on some of the pages that utilises vue...

For instance, say I have two pages: `/home` and `/orders`. Instead of loading `app.js` on every page, I'd like have:

`/home` (most pages look like this)

- `vendor.js`: jquery + bootstrap + jquery plugins
- `home.js`: initializes some jquery plugins (e.g. carousels) on the page

`/orders`

- `vendor.js`
- `vue.js`: I'd like to extract vue because I have multiple entry points
- `order-index.js`: registers page specific vue component and creates vue instance

```
// order-index.js

Vue.component('order-index', require('./components/OrderIndex.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

How can I achieve that using laravel-mix? Or do you guys have any better suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume laravel mix uses weback. With weback you can define different entry points and dynamically create different outputs. (have a look here https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/multiple-entry-points). Then all you need to simply do is enqueue the vue script in the pages you need.

Comment: @Mel Macaluso Yes, laravel mix uses webpack. And it supports multi-entry. The problem is more about vendor extracting. I need to extract multiple vendors and include selected ones on demand. The default laravel mix extracting setup requires to include all the extracted files, e.g.: `manifest.js`, `vendor1.js`, `vendor2.js`, `app.js`